# Solving a non-algebraic equation at the symbolic level

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, version-13.3

Versions 10, 11, 12, 13.0.0.0 and 13.2.0.0 solves the following system of equations

```
 Solve[{1 + E^t r s == s, (s - 1)*(1 + 3 t) == s, r^3 s^3 == t, r > 0}] // Simplify

 (* {{r -> E^(-(4/3) ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4])/(1 + 4 ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4]),
 s -> 1 + 1/(4 ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4]),
 t -> 4/3 ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4]}} *)
```

However, version 13.3.1.0 only gives numerical results:

```
 (* {{r -> (E^(-(1/(3 (-1 + Root[{3 - E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) - 12 # + 18 #^2 - 12 #^3 + 3 #\
 ^4& , 1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}])))\
 ) (-1 + Root[{3 - E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) - 12 # + 18 #^2 - 12 #^3 + 3 #^4& , 1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}]\
 ))/Root[{3 - E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) - 12 # + 18 #^2 - 12 #^3 + 3 #^4& , 1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}], 
   s -> Root[{3 - E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) - 12 # + 18 #^2 - 12 #^3 + 3 #^4& , 1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}], 
   t -> 1/(3 (-1 + Root[{3 - E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) - 12 # + 18 #^2 - 12 #^3 + 3 #^4& , 1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}])\
 )}} *)
```

Did version 13.3.1.0 lose the ability to solve some equations on a symbolic level ?

Comment: Solutions in terms of `Root` objects are symbolic.

Comment: E.g., the analytic  expression ` 1 + 1/(4 ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4])` is not very useful.

Comment: @Artes: I can ask the question another way: Why doesn't version 13.3.1.0 simplify these expressions?

Comment: Why do you think that the answers in terms of `ProductLog` are simpler?

Comment: @user64494: I don't agree, it's a nice expression that can (after changing `ProductLog` -> `LambertW`) be published in an article, expressions with Root don't have much meaning for me.

Comment: I'm using `13.0.1` and I get results in terms of `ProductLog`.  I guess this can be demostrated symbolically with *Mathematica* that the both expressions are equal, even though basic use of `FullSimplify` doesn't work.

Comment: However, there is some change since version 13.3.1.0 (maybe 13.3.0.0 ?) that cannot be considered an improvement of the program.

Comment: `13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)` also produces answers in terms of `Root`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Artes guessed, Mathematica 13.3.1 on Windows 10  can demonstrate both solutions are equal. For example,

```
FullSimplify[1 + 1/(4 ProductLog[3^(1/4)/4]) - 

Root[{-E^((-1 + #)^(-1)) + 3 (-1 + #)^4 &, 
1.98050899605605520782910966112364513358`20.301154892036543}]]
```

> `0`

Comment: That is true, but why does version 13.3.1.0 give a less pleasant result in terms of usability? This cannot be considered an improvement of the program, in my view it is the opposite. See comments above for more.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec: Thank you for your personal opinion.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec I agree that is not an improvement.   I suspect this is a consequece of change in the system on a different level where it might seem an improvement. However similar issues apear more frequently.